# reinitializing tiny mce 4 results in a blank editor

Tags: ajax, tinymce, initialization

tinymce works well the first time i initialize a textarea with a particular ID.

if i remove the textarea and later reinsert the textarea via ajax, reinitializing the textarea will give me a blank tinymce editor. inspecting the html, it seems that the iframe content for the editor isn't loaded.

i've seen a lot of hacks that use commands such as:
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=22977
but this seems to be v3 oriented and doesn't work for me with v4.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop all editor on the page and init each one, but it will give you an idea on how you select which editor the command should be sent to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (edId in tinymce.editors) {
        tinymce.editors[edId].execCommand('mceAddControl', false, edId);
    }
});
```

You could use something like this for just a specific editor based on element class/ID

```
tinymce.editors[$(".editHover").attr('id')].execCommand('mceAddControl', false, $(".editHover"));
```

Comment: Thanks Christoffer. it seems that the cause of my problems was that i was moving the editor in the DOM after initializing it. it's working well now that i'm not doing that anymore. thanks!