# TinyMCE 4 - blank editor after moving textarea

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE Jquery version 4, and this is my (simplified) scenario:

```
<div id="a">
    <textarea id="t_a"/>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <textarea id="t_b"/>
</div>
```

I build an editor out of both textareas

```
$('textarea').tinymce(_conf);
```

Users with specific UI controls may switch the 2 divs. Basically i'm doing

```
$('#b').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

What happens is that i get a blank editor, where no edit possible as the iframe has no content at all.
I've run a few attempts with no luck...

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578395/reinitializing-tiny-mce-4-results-in-a-blank-editor) highlighting a problem similar to mine (unless i'm wrong) but it wasn't every helpful.

My latest solution at the moment is

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, t_b.attr('id'));                    
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, t_b.attr('id'));

$.when( _doSomeAnimation() ).done(function() {
    b.insertBefore(a);
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, t_b.id);
});
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit more i found out that 'mceAddControl' and 'mceRemoveControl' commands are not supported anymore in v.4, being replaced by 'mceAddEditor' and 'mceRemoveEditor' respectively.

Comment: this works but when I try to implement it, it adds the control with default configuration and does not pick the configuration I have set for other tinyMCE editors on the page. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Is this really the final solution for tinyMCE4? No better way?

Comment: I actually found another and more compact solution: knowing the id of the textarea, you can remove and reinitialize the related editor.
The code snippet above would so become:
`$.when( _doSomeAnimation() ).done(function() {
    b.insertBefore(a);
    window.tinymce.editors[t_b.prop('id')].remove();
    t_b.tinymce(_conf)
});`